# AJAX calling Does Not Update Database

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm creating a system, and in part of it, you have to be able to remove employees from their Saturday shifts. To do this, you click on an icon which calls the JavaScript function "removeEmpFromSaturday" and submits the corresponding parameters.

In that Script, it should then update values via an Ajax request, that should update my database and remove the employee from his/her Saturday shift.

However, the PHP page that I point to, is never actually called/requested ("Evidenced by Alerts on the PHP page").

I'm relatively new to AJAX and perhaps my syntax is entirely wrong for this function, so any additional pointers would be greatly appreciated.

For reference, when I alert any of the values "id, loc, week, year" they all give me the correct values I'm expecting, so it isn't a problem there.

Below is the code where I believe the problem lies:

```
<script>

function removeEmpFromSaturday(id, loc, week, year){

    xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.open("GET", "includes/ajax/remove_emp_from_saturday.php?e_id=" + id + 
                      "&location=" + loc + "&week=" + week + "&year=" + year, false);
    xhttp.send();
    resetPlanner();
}

</script>
```

The PHP code I'm pointing too:

```
<?php require_once dirname(__FILE__)."/../admin_header.php" ;?>

<script>alert("STARTED");</script>

<?php

if(isset($_REQUEST['e_id'])){
    $emp_id = escape($_REQUEST['e_id']);
    $loc = escape($_REQUEST['location']);
    $week = escape($_REQUEST['week']);
    $year = escape($_REQUEST['year']);

    $query = "SELECT e_hp_daily_pat FROM employees WHERE e_id = '{$emp_id}' ";
    $get_hp_daily_pat_query = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_hp_daily_pat_query);
    $e_hp_daily_pat = escape($row['e_hp_daily_pat']);

    $query = "SELECT * FROM slots WHERE s_location = '{$loc}' AND s_day = '6' 
        AND s_week = '{$week}' AND s_year = '{$year}' ";
    $get_emps_query = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_emps_query);
    $s_real_sub = escape($row['s_real_sub']);
    $s_emps = escape($row['s_emps']);
    $s_emps = explode(";", $s_emps);
    $process = false;
    $e_match = 0;
    foreach($s_emps as $emp){
        if($emp == $emp_id){
            unset($s_emps[$e_match]);
            $process = true;
          }
        $e_match++;
    }

    if($process == true){
        $s_emps = implode(";", $s_emps);
        $s_real_sub -= $e_hp_daily_pat;
        $query = "UPDATE slots SET s_emps = '{$s_emps}', s_real_sub = '{$s_real_sub}' WHERE s_location = '{$loc}' AND s_day = '6' AND s_week = '{$week} AND s_year = '{$year}' ";
        $set_emps_query = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
      }
    }
?>

<script>alert("COMPLETE");</script>
```

And please before anyone mentions it, I understand I am not binding my parameters and that is slightly outdated in mysqli, I will update that later.

Comment: "Evidenced by Alerts on the PHP page" — That isn't evidence. You aren't loading the output of the PHP script into the browser as a new web page. You aren't doing **anything** with the output of the PHP script.

Comment: On top of what @Quentin said: did you check your path? Are you sure the file is where you say it is? :)

Comment: debug that where you have issue, is your server call executing properly put echo statements to debug.

Comment: @Quentin that isn't really a helpful comment at all. I'm attempting to call to a PHP page via Ajax that changes values in the database. I have an alert on my PHP page I'm clearly trying to call to, and it isn't showing indicating to me that I have a problem with the call. You understand I'm posting on here for help?

Comment: @Jordumus I did check the path, and it's in the correct location. Not only that, but I make another call in a similar fashion, with a similar path (same folders etc) and there wasn't a problem with that one.

Comment: @cmprogram — When you type a URL into the browser's address page (**not** what you are doing here), then the browser will make an HTTP request to that URL. It will take the response. Then it will parse the HTML. If it finds a script element, it will interpret the contents as JS. If there are alerts then it will show the alerts.

Comment: @cmprogram — When you make a request with XMLHttpRequest (which you **are** doing here), then the browser will make an HTTP request to that URL. It will take the  response. It will expose the raw content of that response to JS. It **won't** parse the HTML. It **won't** interpret script elements. It **won't** execute JS. It **won't** show alerts.

Comment: @Quentin Correct. Which is why I have identified the problem lies in the code I have posted. Unfortunately, I'm not sure from there what I have done wrong. Edit (After seeing second comment) - Ah. I see. I'll have to use something else to help debug then.

Comment: Could you show us the relevant part of your php code?

Comment: @Jordumus Yes, no bother, I'll update the post in two minutes.

Comment: Code has been updated to display PHP.

Comment: Could you, instead of your `alert()` calls, add `echo` calls in the PHP itself instead?

Comment: @Jordumus Interesting... thanks to that suggestion and Quentin 's comments, it appears the PHP code IS being found. However, it is not updating the values in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error in your update query:

```
   $query = "UPDATE slots SET s_emps = '{$s_emps}', s_real_sub = '{$s_real_sub}' WHERE s_location = '{$loc}' AND s_day = '6' AND s_week = '{$week} AND s_year = '{$year}' ";
```

You're missing a "'" after the `s_week`

```
   $query = "UPDATE slots SET s_emps = '{$s_emps}', s_real_sub = '{$s_real_sub}' WHERE s_location = '{$loc}' AND s_day = '6' AND s_week = '{$week}' AND s_year = '{$year}' ";
```

General advice: to debug your php code, try not to use `<script>alert("")</script>`, but instead use `echo` calls from within the php directly.

This will assure you that the php is found and parsed.

Comment: You're entirely spot on. Great find. I''ll take that advice in the future, only debug in the exact language you're referencing. Thanks!

Comment: I would suggesting using a POST request (or DELETE) rather than a GET. The semantics of GET is that the request implies no side-effect on the server's state. Consequently, subsequent GET requests may be cached.
A delete query has an obvious side-effect, and you wouldn't want it to get cached.